# PayPal Subscriptions: meaning of ACTIVE vs. APPROVED statuses

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

When creating a subscription using the [PayPal Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create), the status value in the HTTP response can be APPROVED but it can also be ACTIVE.

How are these different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ACTIVE Subscription is, well: active. It will do everything you expect it to do over time.

An APPROVED Subscription was recently approved (consented to) by a payer, nothing more. It won't do anything unless activated.

---

What happens after a Subscription is approved? The default [user_action](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-application_context) is `SUBSCRIBE_NOW`, which *activates the subscription immediately and automatically on approval*. However, you can change that by setting to `CONTINUE` instead, and show a final review step after the return, before activating with a separate API call.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to get the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED in a timely manner. Can I use the BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED to update my users subscription status from guest to member? Or can the payment be denied and the subscription still show as being activated?

Comment: You can use more webhooks if you want, they aren't essential but there's one for BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT.FAILED to reverse an active state if you need to do something in the case of payment failures.

Comment: Does paypal allow a subscription to be activated if the payment fails?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/customize/payment-failure-retry/